# I try to create two ExpansionTile if one tile open the another tile will close and the but in my code the tow Tile will automatically generate space

Tags: flutter, dart

Here I create two ExpansionTile they automatically create space between them

````dart
SizedBox(
                height: 500,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: ExpansionTile(
                          title: const Text('developer'),
                          children: List.generate(
                            successState.developerList.length,
                            (index) => EmployeeTileWidget(
                                employee: successState.developerList[index]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: ExpansionTile(
                          title: const Text('testerList'),
                          children: List.generate(
                            successState.testerList.length,
                            (index) => EmployeeTileWidget(
                                employee: successState.testerList[index]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
            ),


flutter```

`the two ExpansionTile will automatically generate space `
````

I try to create two expand and collapse widget if one open the another stay on the bottom of the  SizedBox. but in my case the one ExpansionTile will open the another one will go the end of the list so if need to scroll the end of the list to open the another  ExpansionTile

I need to create if one ExpansionTile will open the another one will stay the bottom of the SizedBox if the if one ExpansionTile close then the another one will go back to the normal position

Comment: Wrapping with expanded will divide the children. By your code, each child will have `250px` for each `ExpansionTile`. Just remove it

Comment: without ExpansionTile how to generate List.generate

Comment: sorry, i mean remove the `Expanded` widget. Since you are use it in a `Column` , you do not need to wrap with `Expanded`

Comment: I have long list without Expanded it will throw error

Comment: if you specify the height of `SizeBox` = 500,  you can wrap the `Column` widget with `SingleChildScrollView` to make it scrollable. Or change Colum widget with another scrollable widget

Comment: if in this case the one ExpansionTile will open the another ExpansionTile will go to the end of the first list it's hart to use

Comment: no. Have you try it? let me provide you example in answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your parent widget with scrollable widget and let the children has it own height.

see the code

```
SizedBox(
      height: 500,
      child: Column(children: [
        ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 300),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ExpansionTile(
            title: const Text('testerList'),
            children: List.generate(
              3,
              (index) => Text("ssdasdas"),
            ),
          )),
        ),
        ExpansionTile(
          title: const Text('testerList'),
          children: List.generate(
            7,
            (index) => Text("ssdasdas"),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    )
```

cant attach any image, since Stackoverflow error. you can check this plyaground.

result:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=c3f0c6f4dcc5d0705d32b7ba10f4a429

Comment: I have a long list if one ExpansionTile will open the  another ExpansionTile will go the end of the previous ExpansionTile

Comment: is there any way to stop if one ExpansionTile will open the another  ExpansionTile will stay on the bottom of the SizedBox

Comment: you can set maximum height both

Comment: i have update the code, check the playground to try it

Comment: is this possible if one open the another one will automatically close

Comment: I think technically its possible. you may try this workaround https://stackoverflow.com/q/51697901/12838877